# Why doesn't this method actually affect the SQL query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method which is meant to return a number of items from the database based on a set of criteria:

```
scope :expired_not_marked, lambda { |client|
items = where('items.status > 0 AND items.expires_at < ? AND items.expired_at IS NULL AND (winning_bid_id IS NULL OR winner_id IS NULL)', Time.now)
unless client.nil?
    items.where('items.client_id = ?', client.id)
end
}
```

It's being called as `Item.expired_not_marked nil`. When I run this from the IRB I get a lot of results but it shows the SQL query being executed as:

```
SELECT `items`.* FROM `items`
```

It's pretty obviously that was not the original author's intent. As a result the same items are being processed over and over.

Why is this broken, and how do I fix it. The where clause seems correct. The above method is within the `item.rb` model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that your `lambda` sometimes returns `nil` and a scope that returns `nil` won't do anything useful.

The `lambda` will return the value of its last expression. In your case, that expression will be the `unless`. So if `client` is not `nil`, it will return this:

```
items.where('items.client_id = ?', client.id)
```

and all will be good. But if `client.nil?` is true, the `unless` will evaluate to `nil` and your scope will return `nil`. I think you'd be better off with something like this:

```
scope :expired_not_marked, lambda { |client|
  items = where('items.status > 0 AND items.expires_at < ? AND items.expired_at IS NULL AND (winning_bid_id IS NULL OR winner_id IS NULL)', Time.now)
  unless client.nil?
    items = items.where('items.client_id = ?', client.id)
  end
  items
}
```

That way you always have a clear, explicit, and well defined return value.

---

The [ActiveRecord Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) recommends that you use class methods for scopes that take arguments:

> Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes.

so you could also do this if the `lambda` approach is too noisy:

```
def self.expired_not_marked(client)
  items = where('items.status > 0')
  items = items.where('items.expires_at < ?', Time.now)
  items = items.where('items.expired_at IS NULL')
  items = items.where('winning_bid_id IS NULL OR winner_id IS NULL')
  unless client.nil?
    items = items.where('items.client_id = ?', client.id)
  end
  items
}
```

You don't have to use a class method of course. And you don't have to break the query into a bunch of little `where` calls for each component but it might be easier to read this way.

Comment: Thank you -- and I really appreciate the complete explanation. Need to attack the rails documentation on models this evening!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is consistently being returned from the lambda.  The last evaluated expression of a lambda will be its return value if there is no explicit `return` statement.

```
scope :expired_not_marked, lambda { |client|
  items = where('items.status > 0 AND items.expires_at < ? AND items.expired_at IS NULL AND (winning_bid_id IS NULL OR winner_id IS NULL)', Time.now)
  unless client.nil?
    items.where('items.client_id = ?', client.id)
  end
  items
}
```

If I were writing this, I would suggest a `scoped` object.  This would ensure that only one SQL query is performed.

```
scope :expired_not_marked, lambda { |client|
  items = Items.scoped.where('items.status > 0 AND items.expires_at < ? AND items.expired_at IS NULL AND (winning_bid_id IS NULL OR winner_id IS NULL)', Time.now)
  items = items.where('items.client_id = ?', client.id) unless client.nil?
  items.all
}
```